# Dependence of the neutron-freeze-out temperature

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics

What is the physical explanation for the dependence for the freeze-out temperature $T_\text{F0}$ of the neutrons as a function of the number of degrees of freedom $g^\star$?

$$T_\text{F0}=\left(\frac{1.66}{G_F^2m_\text{PL}}\right)^{1/3} g_\star^{1/6} $$

Why does the temperature rise, implying that the decoupling happens *earlier* in the history of the universe, with a large number of degrees of freedom?

Reference: Grupen, Astroparticle Physics, Chapter 10.3